# Swift bar at the bottom of bar button item in toolbar

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am using a toolbar(at the bottom part of the screen, not as in the printscreen) and I am trying to add a bar at the bottom of the bar button that was last tapped, as in the printscreen(the baby blue bar on top of the blue bar).

Any idea how I could do this?

[image]

Comment: i think the best for you is to use https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Comment: You can use an image view with background color as blue. Then show/hide this image view when select/deselect the bar button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it programatically, then set the navbar y position at the bottom part, you wont be able to do it using Storyboard.